# cordova.js not working on remote page

Tags: php, javascript, cordova

I'm very new in phonegap and i'm working on simple remote index.php file. When i use the example code below in local index.html, it works. But when i use it on remote page, it's not working. i have the latest phonegap 2.9.0. Is there anything that i'm missing? thanks.

// Code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  alert("just work!");
}
</script>
```

Comment: What php page? Give more details.

Comment: do you have set access-origin * on config.xml ?

Comment: yes, access-origin * is inside the config.xml

Comment: php page is on the remote server and the eventlistener code above is inside that php page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load cordova.js locally, so you can't use a remote index.html

Source: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_functions_from_external_website